# Events for native controls in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: events, xamarin.forms, documentation, native

I just checked out consuming [native UI iOS/Android controls in Xamarin Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-views/xaml). One thing I don't understand is what events to specify as triggering an update for bindings. The article mentions `UISwitch` as an example and specifies the `ValueChanged` event for triggering updating bindings. But where can I find information about which events can be used for other iOS and Android controls?

As an example I tried `UITextView` and couldn't find any info on which events is being supported in [the official docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview). Some experimenting and I found I could use an event called "`Changed`", but there has to be some docs somewhere for this I guess. Antone know where?

Answer (score 0):

iOS uses the delegate pattern heavily.  UITextView uses the [UITextViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate) - in native iOS you would provide your own delegate that is responsible for responding to events raised by the control

Comment: Yes, but when incorporating native controls in XAML I need to name the event to be used. I can only assume Xamarin then takes care of building the delegate and named method (event) but if that was the case I would call it `TextViewDidChange`, right? Instead it turns out the correct event for `UITextView` is just `Changed`. I first suspected there might be a naming convention going on, where I would drop the name of the control and the "Did" part, leaving only "Changed" but that seems inconsistent with `ValueChanged` for `UISwitch`.

Comment: the Xamarin docs clearly identify which events each control supports - https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextView/#Public_Events

Comment: Thanks Jason. I hadn't thought of checking out Xamarin's docs on iOS controls (duh! - I need a vote-down for poor research on this one). Please go ahead and edit your previous reply, or write a new one, so I can mark it as the answer. Cheers!